# Hyperledger fabric testing endorsement policy AND in JAVA SDK

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric

I am working with following demo of JAVA sdk: https://github.com/IBM/blockchain-application-using-fabric-java-sdk

To test endorsement policy where admin or user from Org1 and Org2 need to sign a transaction, I have instantiated the chaincode fabcar with endorsement policy 'AND('Org1.member', 'Org2.member')'. Now I am trying to figure how do I need to modify transaction proposal request (in class org.app.chaincode.invocation.InvokeChaincode) so that it gets signed by both Org1 and Org2.

Please feel free to point of if there is any existing resource that I have missed. I have some experience with C# but new to both hyperledger and JAVA.

Endorsement policy in YAML looks as follows:

```
identities:
    user1: {"role": {"name": "member", "mspId": "Org1MSP"}}
    user2: {"role": {"name": "member", "mspId": "Org2MSP"}}
    admin1: {"role": {"name": "admin", "mspId": "Org1MSP"}}
    admin2: {"role": {"name": "admin", "mspId": "Org2MSP"}}

policy:
    2-of:
      - 1-of:
        - signed-by: "user1"
        - signed-by: "admin1"

      - 1-of:
        - signed-by: "user2"
        - signed-by: "admin2"
```